# How can I tell if my old Overhead Door 55A is compatible with this Genie opener?

Tags: garage, garage-door

I have an [Overhead Door Model 55A](https://www.manualslib.com/products/Overhead-Door-55a-3554456.html) over 30 years old garage door opener. How can I tell if compatible with this [new Genie one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B084GCTSJ7)?

[image]

Comment: How or why would two door openers need to be compatible? What does compatibility mean here?

Comment: Garage door openers are pretty much universal. Unless your door is really close to the ceiling or you have some other issue then it should work. If you're unsure if it will be a good match then provide some details about your door. Size of door, aluminum or wood, clearance to ceiling.

Comment: If you are replacing the old one, you replace **all** of its parts and sensors with the parts from the new one. The don't need to be "compatible" in any meaningful way, they won't be working together.

Comment: The only part of the old opener you _might_ reuse is the angle iron attached to the ceiling that holds it up. Even that, though, you'll have to loosen the bolts to adjust the pieces to match up with the mounting points on the new opener. Oh, you'll also reuse the electrical outlet in the ceiling.

Comment: OP Probably wants to know if they can use the new door opener for their garage door. If there's any worry (like an exceptionally large/heavy garage door) just find the model number on the old opener and look the specs up online. Compare those specs to the new opener's specs.

Comment: Can I switch to belt drive?

Comment: Can you switch to belt drive? Yes, by installing a belt-driven garage door opener. Can you modify the existing one to use belt drive parts? Probably, but if you're asking us here, you _probably_ don't have the engineering chops to do so. (Nothing personal, that's not a conversion I'd attempt, either.)

Answer (score 1):

You have basely three choices. 1. Do nothing. 2. Replace the complete door opener system including the controls etc that come with it. No worry you will not be using the old parts. 3. Hire a company to come in and repair it. If you have gone that route they probably suggestd #2.

You can always call customer service at the Door company and the lift company to see what they tell you. More then likely it will be #2. Consider it has provided service for over 30 years in all types of weather etc you have gotten  very good usage from it.